# Omitting the second half of bentching

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, bentching

I need some help finding sources for great people who left out the second half of *bentching* (i.e. everything from the *harachamans* and on, after the four blessings). Most people seem to have the custom to say that part, and that custom must have been around for a long time because the Tur (Orach Chayim 189) defends this practice, but I have heard that Rav Chaim Soloveitchik and the Vilna Gaon did not say that part. However, I have never seen sources discussing the practice of either of these two rabbis and was wondering if anyone could provide such sources, or sources discussing the practice of any other great people who did not say the second half of *bentching*.

Comment: Ever?  I can give you some who did not say it on Shabbos.

Comment: The Pathway to Prayer Bentcher does mention one, but I don't have it on me now. The last part of bentching isn't obligaory (Tur 189, Aruch Hashulchan 189:7), so it wouldn't surprise me if some great rabbis decided not to say it.

Comment: Before you start asking about people who don't say it, can you give any reason why anyone should say it?

Comment: @DoubleAA Minhag isn't reason enough? After all, it is in every siddur/bentcher I've ever seen.

Comment: @Matt I didn't say it wasn't sufficient, but no one has asserted that there is a minhag to say them. Many siddurim print lots of things which there is no minhag to say (eg. Tikkun Chatzot). Showing that such a minhag existed at the time of the rabbis in question would help make the question hold water.

Comment: @DoubleAA true, but this is also mentioned by almost all of the later poskim as if it were something that's generally said, especially the Tur who tries to defend the minhag against his brother.

Comment: @Matt So add that information to the question!

Comment: The Rambam includes the Harachaman's in his siddur.

Comment: See Likutei Mahrich ,tgere are those who held one can skip the bakashos if one needs to be somewhere

Answer (score 5):

According to סידור הגר"א בנגלה ובנסתר  the Vilna Gaon only omitted those verses on Shabbath.

In the 1971 edition, section one, page קנט includes them.

In section three, נוסח התפילות והברכות לדעת הגר"א, note 90, it says:

בברהמ"ז לא היה הגר"א אומר בשבת רק עד הרחמן הוא יפרנסנו בכבוד ולא עד בכלל ולא יותר.

On that note, there is a footnote 116, which says this is according to eyewitness accounts of his students.