# Cut-off birkat hamazon

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, nuschaot, bentching

As a complement to this question on [Shortened Birkat Hamazon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93929/11501), I would like to better understand the practice I saw of stopping Birkat Hamazon after the fourth blessing on Shabbat and not saying the *Harachaman*s and the closing text.

I believe it comes from the idea one should not make specific asks on Shabbat although others are saying that asks as part of an organized prayer are all right.

- Where is this custom coming from?
- How widepread is it?
- Are there communities where it is the norm and rabbanim supporting it?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36495/759

Comment: Maybe it would be interesting to turn around the question, and ask for the origins of these supplications, but I'm afraid we wouldn't get further than [Tur](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/טור_אורח_חיים_קפט) and [Rambam](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1508045/jewish/Order-of-Prayers-Text-of-the-Grace-After-Meals.htm)